# Prevent matplotlib from interpreting underscore as subscript in plot title

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to put a filename, that includes underscores, as the `title` of a plot.  This gets rendered as defining a subscript character, since by default I have LaTeX interpretation on.  I'd like to prevent matplotlib from applying LaTeX to this string, while leaving my default `text.usetex` as `True` in my matplotlib configuration file.

How do I do this?

In my version, `1.3.1` (Ubuntu 14), I do not have an option to pass in a `usetex` keyword argument, as indicated in the documentation.

Comment: I strongly suggest upgrading!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably something like this (untested):

```
title = 'I_hate_subscripts'
title = title.replace('_', '\_')
plt.title(title)
```